# Is there a way to stop the WinForms designer defaulting to control Load event

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio

This drives me nuts. In the Visual Studio WinForms designer, if you double-click a control it will produce a XXXX_Load handler for that control. This is never, ever, what you want. You want Click event or a Changed event or more likely to go to the existing Click event. You do NOT was a new Load event. It is worse because a double click can happen by accident. You click once, then again - bingo a Load event handler. I use a pen-tablet combo and double clicks are very easy!

Can someone tell me if there is a way to stop this happening. I would like a Click handler. I would settle for nothing happening.

Comment: I do not get this issue.  The only time VS creates a _Load event handler is when I double click a form.  Otherwise, the event I get depends on which control I am double clicking.  This has held true for me since VS2003 and both c# and VB.

Comment: Just press Ctrl+Z and click Yes.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One way to achieve that is inheriting the control and modifying the [DefaultEventAttribute](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.defaulteventattribute%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

> Specifies the default event for a component.

```
[DefaultEvent("Click")]
public class MyRadionButton : RadionButton {
}
```

But some care/extra work may need to be done when you override a control. You need to keep that in mind when using this approach.

Comment: Now this is a good answer because quite a lot of the control I use are my own -- probably why I see so many _Load events.

Comment: Yes, if you have your own controls, that's the way to go.

Answer (score 2):

In addition to Mehrzad's answer, you can completely disable it by passing an empty string to the `DefaultEvent` attribute:

```
[DefaultEvent("")]
public class MyCustomControl : UserControl
{

}
```

This works because the default control designer uses the [ComponentDesigner.DoDefaultAction](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.design.componentdesigner.dodefaultaction(v=vs.110).aspx) when the control is double clicked. By default, this uses reflection to look up the method signature of the default event. If it can't find it, it doesn't do anything.

Comment: What about not including the attribute at all? Does it do anything in that case?

Comment: Yes, it uses the default event handler of its parent, which if it hasn't been overridden (like for a button), is the `Load` event.

Comment: Nice to know, thanks. So, the default of the default is `Load` :D